# Are there ready tools to check for gaps in list of filenames which are monotonically increasing?

Tags: linux, python

I have been given several hundred directories with millions of files in each of them.
E.g.

```
DirA
+----+ A_000001.txt
     |
     + A_000002.txt
     |
     + ... etc..
```

I want to ensure that the files exists for every number from 000001 until 999999.
So if the file `A_678123.txt` is missing, the tool should report that. Currently I am creating a bit array & then it takes a `ls` output and sets a 1 for every bit position that corresponds to the parsed file number.

Is there a tool (or a combination of tools) that can replace my hacky python script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a combination of `seq`, `sort`, and `uniq`:

```
# Get a list of all the files in DirA
cd DirA
ls . > files.txt
# Get a list of all expected files
seq -f "A_%06.0f.txt" 0 999999 > expected.txt
# Find unique entries
sort files.txt expected.txt | uniq -u
```

You may have to adjust the arguments to `seq` to match the names of your files.

Once that is working, you can try doing it without using temporary files:

```
cd DirA
sort <(ls .) <(seq -f "A_%06.0f.txt" 0 999) | uniq -u
```

Then, once you're ready to search through all your directories:

```
for d in ./*/; do
  pushd "$d"
  sort <(ls .) <(seq -f "A_%06.0f.txt" 0 999) | uniq -u
  popd
done
```

You should get an output similar to this, which lists each directory and every missing file in that directory:

```
./DirA/
A_000371.txt
./DirB/
A_000881.txt
./DirC/
A_000101.txt
A_000191.txt
```